# PDF locked for editing

Tags: pdf

Imagine a PDF file with some text. I want to hide it using Adobe Acrobat following a naive approach.

- I place over this text a black rectangle.
- I save this PDF with the option "not allow to change".

What routines does PDF format implement to protect the change? Is the text actually still there and can be somehow extracted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the text is still there and it's trivial to reveal.

A PDF can't be "locked for editing", because all the contents of the file must be readable in order to display it.

Think of it analogous to an HTML page, with some text, covered by a black box. It would be trivial for anyone to delete the black box to reveal the text.

The only way to make the text truly unrecoverable is to actually delete all traces of it.

Answer (score 0):

That approach has lead to some [embarrassing leaks of classified information](https://slate.com/technology/2016/06/house-democrats-improperly-redacted-documents-wrong-but-they-re-not-alone.html).

Acrobat Pro contains a proper Redaction tool, Std does not. Used correctly, the process produces a redacted copy of the PDF, where the information is actually removed. How-to is available in [Adobe site](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/resources/how-to-redact-a-pdf.html).

I've seen articles and papers about unredacting protected info. These apply to using [pixelation for reduction](https://bishopfox.com/tools/unredacter) or [using Glyph positions to break reduction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.02285.pdf) etc. These methods don't work when reduction is done properly - since the info is no longer present in the redacted PDF, it can't be recovered from it either.

Some other commercial PDF editing tools may also have a proper reduction capability.

There are also freeware tools. From what I can see, the vast majority of them actually redacts nothing, you can just cover stuff up with rectangles. Which, as previously noted, is trivial to break. Search for something along the lines of `pdf redaction freeware` to find and evaluate the possibilities. If the tool talks about using rectangle tool for redaction, it's a no-go.

You can actually restrict usage of a PDF. You can for example allow viewing but deny editing or printing the document, or allow low-quality printing etc. When you have the PDF open, you'll find the available options under **File** - **Properties** - **Security**.